# What are the OS specific stylesheet properties?

Tags: html, css

On our site we are using some custom fonts and I have noticed differences on how buttons, input elements and so own vertically align the text. The padding and other properties have different effect on Linux/MAC and PC.

Can you tell me what CSS properties could be causing different results per OS?
Is it better to use em/rem or px or it doesn't matter in this case?

For example the following rule will vertically align text in Chrome on windows but not in Chrome on Ubuntu.

```
.btn {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.2rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OS has nothing to do with the HTML and CSS rendering. Its the browser which is responsible for property difference. Every browser has its own way of implementation so its the browser community which is creating difference in different platforms of browser.To make everything same in all the browsers,it is always recommended to include reset.css at the top

Reset.css

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: I see, so how do you explain the fact that the same html element with the same css properties on the same browser show different results in Ubuntu and Windows. I believe OS does make a different when it comes to custom fonts!

Comment: Its about way of implementing the stuff by browser. Google must have a different implementation for their browser in windows and different implementation for their browser on linux.

Comment: Ok but the result is the same for me :) Btw the reset.css didn't work